# Passing private static array as an argument to public member function in c++?

Tags: c++, function, class, static, pass-by-reference

Online [documents](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/812-static-member-functions/) seem to suggest that a private member variable of a class that is passed as an argument to a public function in the same class needs to be declared as static. Still, I get a compilation error:

```
class C{

private: 
        static std::string table1[50];

public: 
        bool try (){
            helper(&table1);
            return true; 
        }
        bool helper (std::string * table){
            return true; 
        }
```

But I am getting this compilation error:

```
./c:72:31: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'std::string *' (aka
      'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > *') with an rvalue of type
      'std::string (*)[50]'
```

Is there something else that I missed?

Comment: Maybe you meant `helper(table1);`?

Comment: Can you point to the documentation? I can't see any reason why a private member variable used as an argument would need to be static. That would be a severely limiting restriction.

Comment: This is what I need and it ended up working :  try(){helper(table1)}; helper(std::string * table);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `helper` function takes as a parameter a pointer to `std::string`. You are passing to it a pointer to an array of 50 `std::string`. Instead, pass the first element of the array (in this case the array decays to a pointer), like

```
helper(table1);
```

or

```
helper(&table1[0]);
```

I have serious doubts though that that's what you need. Pointers to `std::string` look a bit fishy here. Better use a `std::vector<std::string>`, or `std::array<std::string, 50>`.

Side note: don't call your member function `try()`, as `try` is a reserved C++ keyword.